# Scale a UIView automatically on orientation change to scale proportionaltely to fit in parent view

Tags: ios, uiview, autoresizingmask

A `UIImage` view set to "Aspect Fit" will automatically dynamically scale it's image to fit within the current bounds of the `UIUmageView`, while maintaining the image's proportions. A `UIView` set to "Aspect Fit" does not seem to have this same effect on it's sub-views.

I have tried to set the parent view via code, with the code below, and tried several variations on the auto-resizing mask ( I am not using auto layout). Am I missing something obvious, or do I need to write a little code to compute the right scale for my sub-view based on the current size of the parent view?

```
[self.view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing around with it. This is incomplete, just handles the portrait subview scaling, but works ok so far.

```
if (self.view.bounds.size.width < self.view.bounds.size.height) {
    NSLog(@"view is portrait");
    if (_sview.frame.size.width < _sview.frame.size.height) {
        NSLog(@"subview is portrait");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                         animations:^{
                             _sview.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
                         }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"subview is landscape");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"landscape");
    if (_sview.frame.size.width < _sview.frame.size.height) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                         animations:^{
                             _sview.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.65, 0.65);
                         }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"subview is landscape");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation:

> The content mode specifies how the cached bitmap of the view’s layer is adjusted when the view’s bounds change.

For an image view, this is talking about the image. For a view that draws its content, this is talking about the drawn content. It does *not* affect the layout of subviews.

You need to look at the autoresizing masks in place on the *subviews*. Content mode is a red herring here. If you can't achieve the layout you need using autoresizing masks, then you need to implement `layoutSubviews` and calculate the subview positions and frames manually.

Comment: yeah thanks, I think I will have to do it manually then. Seems like not such a big thing, but also it get's a bit complicated, as I have been working on it for a bit now. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a method or other class that would assist.

Answer (score 2):

- Content modes do not affect the subviews of the view.
- You would use auto-resizing masks to determine how the subviews are
  laid out.
- If that is not sufficient, you may want to implement
  `layoutSubviews`

Referenced from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14111480/1374512

Other useful info on `layoutSubviews`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330162/1374512

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
 self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Or you can try this :

```
// horizontal 
   childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

// vertical 
   childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

// both 
   childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

If you want any further Reference, I think these are two beautiful Questions :

1) [Autoresizing masks programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib?lq=1)

2) [UIView and AutoresizingMask ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741566/uiview-and-autoresizingmask-ignored?rq=1)

Comment: thanks a lot! but from trying these, seems that none of these options scales the sub-view to fit the bounds of the parent view while maintaining the proportionality of the sub-view.